How do Donald Trump's documented actions and statements (2015-2024) align with established academic frameworks of fascism?
There are a lot of debates about that on social media. I see that this stance often comes not as an assumption, but almost like a presupposition—something obvious and simple—and you get downvoted for challenging the notion that Trump is a fascist.
However, I want to understand, from a scientific perspective, whether his statements and actions actually qualify as following fascistic ideas or attitudes based on what he has said and done so far.
I'm aware that there is no consensus of the exact nature of fascistic tactics so answers will likely depend on a specific definition there, but I want to learn in what ways one would put him close or far away there.
With that in mind, I am looking to analyze Donald Trump's documented statements and actions (2015-2024) against two major academic frameworks defining fascist characteristics:

Umberto Eco's "Ur-Fascism" (1995), which identifies 14 common features of fascist ideology,
Robert Paxton's "Five Stages of Fascism" (1998).

Requirements for answers:

Provide specific, documented examples (speeches, tweets, policies, actions)
Include primary sources and citations
Compare these examples directly to specific elements from both frameworks
Note where examples might fulfill or contradict these frameworks
Maintain neutral, academic language
Acknowledge limitations of the analysis

Please focus on verifiable facts rather than interpretations. When possible, include direct quotes and specific dates.

Political terminology is not "scientific", and there are, of course, competing definitions of what constitutes a fascist. This isn't to say that it is purely a matter of opinion. But the point deserves to be made.

Welcome aboard.  I understand your curiosity and trying to solicit information.
But, sorry, we've had this exact question before.  Answering it is purely a matter of opinion.  And that is the case even if one really really dislikes Trump.  Not least because the term fascist itself is very slippery to define. Voting to close.

I've voted to close, but please note that this is a new contributor.  No need to go all ballistic on the voting, folk.  Oh, and read elicit, rather than solicit above.

Right, definitely opinion-based. If a fascist is a right-wing nationalist with authoritarian aspirations, one could say yes. If they have to have some kind of more fundamental identification with the philosophy of Mussolini and company, one could say no. E.g. few political theorists, even those who would call Trump fascist, or perhaps more properly neo-fascist, would say that he counts as a neo-Nazi, because he does not have the specific political views needed for that (though many neo-Nazis do seem to see him as the least bad option).

This question is similar to: What specific political traits classify a political leader as a fascist?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think the question would better be framed as "Is Trumpism fascist?" rather than "Is Trump fascist?". The focus should be on the political ideology (if it can be dignified with that term) rather than the private opinions of its figurehead.  That gets Trump's ad-hoc policy pronouncements and word-salad speeches out of the way.

How the hell can "what criteria makes Trump a fascist?" be closed as "opinion-based" on a political site?

@Steve Because by and large we have a really strict rule against both "aim to discredit" questions and opinion based questions.  We have also closed and deleted this exact question before though that iteration, IIRC, was a straight out aim to discredit.  This one doesn't seem to be - it seems to genuinely ask if there is any ground - but it will still lead to opinion-based answers because Fascism is a) not that clearly defined b) anecdotal (happened 3 times in its original form and c) everybody and his dog has an opinion on it.

@ItalianPhilosopher, surely that is grounds for imposing a higher standard on the answers, rather than closing the question? The concern seems to be that the question may cause the expression of opinions, perhaps in a conclusory way and with fiery disagreement, but I'm very surprised to find that "is major politician X a Yist?" are inherently unanswerable, even if it is only to answer denying that "Yism" has an agreed definition. I mean otherwise we'd be in the absurd position that nobody could ask whether Stalin was a Stalinist.

@Steve We have plenty of questions that get closed for being opinion based that are less prone to it than this one.  And less motivated to be kept open by a dislike of the person.  Anyways, the linked "What specific political traits classify a political leader as a fascist?" question covers much the same ground, is not tied to discrediting anyone and also shows how difficult it is to pin down exactly what Fascism is.

I've voted to reopen this mainly because we have a Q like that about Putin. (It was asked before his full-scale invasion of Ukraine, BTW.) So, it's not out of the Q to ask something like this here. OTOH https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4297/should-we-allow-questions-where-we-are-attempting-to-apply-the-term-fascist-to

Of course this is an opinion-based question. The primary party calling Trump a fascist displays equally many traits of fascism. The appropriate case would be to examine the political landscape at large and examine how the political environment is moving towards fascism as a whole. Any focus on Trump in isolation is purely an attempt at discrediting him specifically as there are many politicians exhibiting similar traits from both sides of the aisle. The act of calling a political opponent a threat to democracy is itself a fascist act when done without proof, evidence, or rationale.

@DavidS Everything is always part-opinion. Questions only shouldn't primarily be opinion based. And answers that on a bit more academical level compare Trumps statements and actions with how they align or not with fascistic customs, well that should be possible. Those who disagree with the outcome can submit their own analysis or simply ignore the result. But surely the political landscape in the US is not equally bad everywhere. People might have a problem that we aim at the future POTUS here (and not some Russian or third world guy), but maybe it's actually true. If only we knew.

"The word Fascism has now no meaning except in so far as it signifies ‘something not desirable’." - George Orwell, 1956

@ItalianPhilosopher In context, that quote is condemning the practice of using language that is charged but loosely defined, as a means of creating a negative association. E.g "that building design is fascist" . Two sentences later, he bemoans "democracy" being employed the same way to convey positive association. It is a misuse of that quote to reference it to bolster the claim that "fascism" cannot be defined and should not be applied to political regimes. It is also from 1946.

The question has changed somewhat since I wrote this answer; I need to review to adjust to the new criteria. I won't change the essence of the answer, just see if I can improve it. Will remove this message when complete.

There are two implied questions here that we should differentiate:

Is Donald Trump (himself, as a person) a fascist?
Does Donald Trump present, promote, or use fascist ideals, attitudes, or ideation?

The second question is much easier to answer given Trump's public speech. Trump explicitly uses typical fascist ideation and actively avoids any condemnation of its use by others. The evidence is hardly controversial:

Explicit and repeated use of historical fascist phrasing: referring to opponents as 'vermin' and 'animals', citing the 'poisoning of the blood' by immigrants. See this Daily Show mashup.
Generally following the ethno-nationalist pattern of equating the term 'American' with his supporters, and suggesting all others are traitors and/or criminals who should be tried and/or deported.
Constant references to some prior (mythical) period of American 'greatness' combined with constant claims that 'he' and 'his people' have been victimized, by some ambiguous and nefarious (deep state) groups that have stolen power away from 'his people'.
A vocal appreciation for unfettered authoritarian leadership, based on the idea that strength and decisiveness are more important that justice and consideration (often couched in gendered conceptions that the first are 'masculine' traits and the second 'feminine')

It's obvious that Trump is invoking fascist tropes as part of a political strategy.
As to the first question of whether Trump (himself) is fascist… I don't think it's useful to refer to individuals as fascist unless they self-identify as such. Fascism refers to a type of nationalist social movement, but most forms of nationalism share an inherent dishonesty or hypocrisy: e.g., they portray themselves as superior but claim to be victims; they describe themselves as noble but ignore or defend ignoble acts by their cohort; they claim to be populist but invariably establish elitist hierarchies and authoritarian structures. In fascism, ideology is more of a facade than a deeply held belief, a facade purposefully adopted to excite and motivate the mass public. It's an open question whether leaders of the movement actually believe the claims they make in public, or whether they recognize an opportunistic moment where they can profit from the emotional lability of the masses. Looking at Trump's history, it's safe to say that he's opportunistic, and willing/able to manipulate both public perception and the legal system. But there's no clear indication that Trump has ever been motivated by idealism or principle, or shown any dedication to any specific public cause.
I don't see that Trump is explicitly fascist in his own right, and he certainly does not identify as such, but he has clearly been using a fascist model to get what he wants.

Kudos on actually separating the person, from the policy.  However, while those are some indicators, they are neither exclusive to Fascism, and do not cover all of its determinants.  IIRC racial policies were not as prominent with Franco and, initially, Musso (who did shift a bit under Nazi pressure).  The Fascists pretty much worshipped the military, mass displays of "strength" and war.  That's not really there with Trump, and yes, it's a doozy of a factor.  That in turn drove an emphasis on boosting natality which is not really a match for Christian intolerance of women's rights.

Most of the characteristics you cite are by no means exclusive to Fascism, though they were certainly leveraged by Fascism.  They, instead, tend to patterns recurringly found in bad governments.  IMHO, it is easy, and lazy, to find correspondences between Trumpism (whatever it is) and Fascism.  But the real risk is that it also causes sitting-on-the-fencers to tune out.  After all, one hallmark of 2024 was a significant increase in minority support,  for Trump, making this a bit of a narrative that those people have no clue.  -1, for answering a Q that should have been ditched right away.

Another missing element is the explicit appeal to Social Darwinism theories that tend to pop up when historians dissect Hitler's rise to power.

@ItalianPhilosopher: Nothing I can do with these comments, which neither address the answer I gave nor propose any necessary changes. This merely seems to be a list of weak objections to the idea that anything intelligent can be said about sociopolitical movements or group behavior. I suggest you either make more effective suggestions, or go write your own answer explaining the importance of this kind of anti-intellectualism. That might be interesting.

Why should I answer a Q that I believe has no justification to exist wrt site rules???  There are other similarities between Hitler and Trump, such as for example locking out the Social Dems and Communists to pass the Enabling Act.  This resembles the attempt to "lock out" the electoral votes from states won by Dems on Jan 6th.  Stacking the courts with pliant judges.  Trump is indeed a very worrying POTUS for democracy. But making those comparisons does not rely on claiming a blanket equivalence to Fascism as a movement and one also needs to be careful not to dismissed as over-alarmist.

Ted, I understand why you think there is something useful to be said here, and there is. I disagree with none of your answer, which is my opinion. And that's kind of precisely the problem. We've already seen at least one known troll try to take advantage of this question by asking if Native Americans as a group are fascist. Another trying to ask if Hitler was fascist. We have a user who once told me that the behavior of certain Jews make them understand why people voted for Hitler agitating to reopen it...I wonder what kind of answer they would give.

Asking questions like this is an invitation to heavily opinion-based answers, even though yours is less so than most. And a lot of those answers, I suspect, are going to come from a far-right perspective that will be light on facts and not particularly helpful for the site. The edit to lay out a specific framework and definition is a good step toward making it not opinion-based, but just asking "Is a leader X-ist" is going to lead to too many opinion-based answers without more clarification.

E.g. imagine a question like "Is Joe Biden fascist?" Sure, a good answer from you that says "probably not" would get most of the upvotes. But then we get two answers that say "Yes, because the USA is fascist," two that say "Yes, because mask mandates," two that say "Yes, because he supports Netanyahu," two that say "Yes, because he is a Communist." Is that really good for the site?

@ItalianPhilosopher: You don't have to answer it if you don't want to. Just stop bothering me with pointless complaints.

@Obie2.0: I understand your concerns, but that's a weakness of this site; we ought to be able to close a question because it lacks foundation. The difference is that there is a valid political question whether Trump's use of ethane-nationalist rhetoric (which is indisputable) will translate into ethno-nationalist policy, and whether his political programme reflect a fascist modality. That is a valid question under site rules, and the fact that it will inevitably stir up a hornet's nest of trolls and idiots is unfortunate, but irrelevant.

@Obie2.0: If we can't talk about Trump's policy tendencies, then we can't talk about US politics, and we might as well just shut down the site in the US. Is that what you want?

Every single point is an opinion here. 1st point is literally a common trope of US political ads for the last 10 years. Doesn't matter which party you look at. But it might be convenient to forget deplorables and garbage. 2nd point is false, at best a disingenuous interpretation of his comments, he references citizens vs non-citizens. Point 3 is false, its no secret the US economy was in a better place before the 70s than it is today. Deep state is another name for bad faith actors putting party politics above government, see recent FEMA hearings.

@DavidS: I'm sorry you feel that way, but let's be clear on one point: you are talking about what DT meant when he spoke; I'm talking about what DT said when he spoke. In other words, I'm merely engaged in observation; you are engaged in interpretation. You're correct that in the modern world a great deal of effort is made to 'spin' politician's actual speech in the most favorable light, and you're certainly welcome to do that (not like I could stop you). But let's not equate your desire to spin with the actual (literal, textual) utterances Trump makes. That's silly.

@TedWrigley The silliness is attempting to examine a single politician, saying they use fascism, and then neglect to integrate that with the common political landscape the politician exists in. Trump's words have been no more fascist than his opposition. The heat of the rhetoric, in general, has raised. To single out any one politician, and then look at that raised rhetoric in isolation, is deceptive at best. The entire political landscape has gotten more toxic. To answer this question properly would explain how Trumps comments are above the mean.

This answers lists the parts of 'fascism' that Trump does match. What parts does he not match and are those parts more or less important?

@JonathanReez: That's a little harder to answer, for a couple of reasons. (1) Fascism is particularly susceptible to the Risky Shift effect, so that their positions and behaviors become continually more extreme and aggressive. We tend to think of mid-20th century fascism in terms of it's heights in the 1940s, but Trumpism is (currently) quite similar to Nazism of the 1930s (and as I stated, I believe that's intentional). 1930 Nazism was unpleasant but not overtly dangerous; it's the risky shift trajectory that's worrisome, not the details.

@JonathanReez: (2) these kinds of nationalist movements are ideologically facile and fluid: they don't care about facts or beliefs in or of themselves, but only about the political potentials and utilization of facts and beliefs. They like broad strokes, and avoid concrete specifics wherever possible. Therefore we have to look at broad strokes. specific differences (and specific identifications, as well) are too superficial and politically malleable to carry much meaning

@TedWrigley Hitler overthrew democracy two (!) weeks after being elected to Parliament in 1933. How is that not extremely dangerous? Also a minor gripe - Nazism and Fascism have several important differences which was a source of tension between Mussolini and Hitler. The two are not equivalent.

@JonathanReez: Hitler in one constitutionally-established emergency powers of his office. Trump has talked about doing the same. The Weimar Republic constituted things differently than we do in the US, and Hitler's position was somewhat different than the position Trump is going to fill, but… [shrug]. You know what they say: virtue has scope, the devil has details. I lean towards the former.

With regards to Paxton it's fairly simple:

I've Hesitated to Call Donald Trump a Fascist. Until Now

Robert O. Paxton On 1/11/21 at 5:13 PM EST


So after Jan 6, Paxton himself has called Donald Trump a fascist. Here is the full source. That doesn't mean that he previously thought he wasn't problematic though. On the contrary, he already compared the cult of personality and the crowds to Hitlers campaigns, saw "lock her up" and forceful handling of hecklers as threat of physical violence, compared the "Proud Boys" with storm troopers (Nazi) and squadristi (Mussolini), saw MAGA hats as uniforms and "America First" and the "arrogance of the leader" as following the fascist model. Compared Hitler's usage of the new medium of the radio with Trumps media influence on Twitter and Fox News. And how he established himself as a bullwark against the advancing left thus in the new and thus fear inducing forms of "feminism, Black Power, gay rights".
Though he was kinda surprised that compared to Germany and Italy in the interwar years, the U.S. is not remotely as fucked up and politically deadlocked as historical breeding grounds for fascism. So compared to that the crisis of Trumps refusal to concede the lost election seemed almost trivial to him. (So my interpretation of that would be that it's rather childish and immature not to concede but that the institutions, the general vibe, the status quo were well enough to shrug that off).
Also while Mussolini and Hitler at least initially gave themselves an anti-capitalism appearance, before teaming up with big business against labor, yet still forced the business people, sometimes against their will, into rearmament. Trump essentially gave big business the deregulation and access to markets that they asked for.
So while there was already plenty to work with, with regards to calling him a fascist, Paxton himself for a long time thought it was better to avoid this emotionally charged label and rather go with something more neutral, though not less damning, like: Oligarch or Plutocrat.

Trump's incitement of the invasion of the Capitol on January 6, 2020 removes my objection to the fascist label. His open encouragement of civic violence to overturn an election crosses a red line. The label now seems not just acceptable but necessary. It is made even more plausible by comparison with a milestone on Europe's road to fascism—an openly fascist demonstration in Paris during the night of February 6, 1934.

So with regards to Paxton, yes, Trump is a fascist.
If you look at his 5 Stages of Fascism though you might realize that these are not focusing on a individual personality traits or mark out individuals as culprits, but that they describe societal developments.
So the question is somewhat ill-fated as it appears to focus on whether Trump personally is a fascist.
The problem is that the fascist system has several roles, from the storm trooper dealing out violence, to the ideologues legitimizing the violence with philosophy, to the demagogues who preach and enhance fears and the necessity for violence, to the opportunists who are not personally into it, but who nonetheless go along with it and thus enable it, and so on.
And each of them are vital for the fascist ascend to power and their continuous exercise of power. So which of these groups would you call fascist and what character traits would that entail?

Just the ideologues? But without supporters in high places, demagogues, opportunists and most important executors, these would just be a bunch of weirdos and lunatics that no one would or could take serious?

Just the executors as they do the actual harm? But what about the system that enabled them? Also how do you deal with that? How do you tell the brainwashed people scared shitless by a society on propaganda from the willing contributors that claim to have only followed orders?

Just the demagogues? But what if they actually believe the bullshit that the ideologues have spread and what about the opportunists that didn't attempt to stop, but that encourage them. Or the executors who should have refused?

Just the opportunists? But they don't actually believe that shit in the first place, they just go along with it, thus enable the crimes of others.


The thing is similar to the definition of "racism is prejudice + power" that many people seem to dislike and get wrong, an individual with prejudices or in that case an individual with an inclination towards authoritarian anti-democratic solutions, "might makes right" and whatnot, is on it's own questionable, BUT for racism and fascism, so entire structural systems of society that permeate every aspect of social life, you'd need more than just 1 fucked up individual. You need people that go along, that actively support, that look the other way, that ease people's discomfort with injustice and so on and on.
So the problem with asking "Is XYZ a fascist" is that people often look at that with the expectation of "are they an awful human being" and if that is not necessarily the case, they might reject the label despite it fitting, because despite not being the worst person on earth, someone can still be an instrumental asset to the worst crimes in human history.
That all being said, Trump certainly has a lot of vices. One can actually almost claim without explicit sources that he is a liar, a fraudster, a cheater and a rapist as he does so blatantly, was sentenced for or even bragged about all of that in broad daylight. And yes that rape trial was a civil not a criminal case, but after

"I don't even wait. And when you're a star, they let you do it. You can do anything. ... Grab 'em by the pussy. You can do anything."

alone describes sexual assault pretty well and that's something he bragged about (even if that bragging was not meant to be public). Which aren't thing that put him closer to fascism, but might make you question his character and honesty when he denies things... And denying everything coincidentally has also been the tactic of his former lawyer Roy Cohn. Who otherwise worked with the McCarthy era prosecutors and mobsters...
Also his track record on racism ranges from housing discrimination of his Management company, to birther conspiracies about Obama, to the central part five for whom Trump called for the reintroduction of the death penalty in all major newspapers in NY and where he explicitly called for HATE:

"The problem with our society is the victim has absolutely no rights and the criminal has unbelievable rights" and, speaking of another case where a woman was raped and thrown out a window, "maybe hate is what we need if we're gonna get something done.

Which yeah undermines the justice system, promotes extrajudical violence, breeds a sentiment of fear (Despite again himself more likely than not (according to a civil trial) being a sexual predator). Or his reaction to the fact that a serial rapist later admitted the deed, which was confirmed by DNA evidence and the accused were released and sued the city

In June of that year, Trump called the settlement "a disgrace" and said that the group's guilt was still likely: "Settling doesn't mean innocence. [...] These young men do not exactly have the pasts of angels."

Which he apparently still stands by.
And you could go further with what he did in the case of Joe Arpaio. A Sheriff who was charged by the DoJ with:
Discriminatory policing practices including unlawful stops, detentions and arrests of Latinos;
Unlawful retaliation against individuals exercising their First Amendment right to criticize MCSO’s policies or practices, including but not limited to practices relating to its discriminatory treatment of Latinos; and
Discriminatory jail practices against Latino inmates with limited English proficiency by punishing them and denying them critical services.  

A failure to implement policies guiding deputies on lawful policing practices;
Allowing specialized units to engage in unconstitutional practices;
Inadequate training;
Inadequate supervision;
An ineffective disciplinary, oversight and accountability system; and
A lack of sufficient external oversight and accountability.   

Use of excessive force;
Police practices that have the effect of significantly compromising MCSO’s ability to adequately protect Latino residents; and
Failure to adequately investigate allegations of sexual assaults.  

And who received a Pardon from Trump before he was even sentenced.

Constitutional scholars opposed the pardon, as "an assault on the federal judiciary, the constitution and the rule of law itself"

So again you don't have to do something, you can also willfully enable something.
To lots of half-assed denials or non-denials of white supremacy... you know what you can read the entire wikipedia article as that is too longer to cover in full detail. Though one case mentioned in the article might further be interesting with regards to fascism, where 2 white man attacked a Hispanic, homeless person sleeping outside of a subway station in Boston with the words:

"Donald Trump was right, all these illegals need to be deported."

So regardless of whether he himself has those intentions his followers certainly do more than occasionally feel encouraged to interpret his words like that.
And his own response:

“I will say that people who are following me are very passionate. They love this country and they want this country to be great again. They are passionate. I will say that, and everybody here has reported it.” source

to a hate crime committed in his name was not to distance himself from the perpetrators or to argue that that is not what he or they stand for, but to excuse them arguing that his followers are very passionate (which includes these 2?) and that they want America to be great again (his slogan)... by beating up homeless people?
So again the question isn't so much if Trump himself is a terrible person, but Trump enabling and encouraging terrible people and a societal mood that goes beyond individuals being terrible, is the thing that brings it from individual malice to fascism. And yeah Trump does appeal to a crowd that is more and more exemplifying fascist stages and regardless of whether he started that dynamic or whether he merely positively interferes with it, that does at some point no longer matter.
Like Trump not conceding the election when you clearly lost is childish, but people storming a public building threatening to lynch representatives and take matters into their own hand, encouraged and supported by Trump is were apparently at least Paxton drew his line.
(Wikipedia summary of the 5 stages used for comparision)

1.Intellectual exploration, where disillusionment with popular democracy manifests itself in discussions of lost national vigor

Not sure the U.S. passed that stage long ago, as that sounds like the plot of a lot of 80s action movies, of a country in decline and the willingness of an individual to take matters into his own hands and shoot everyone up... Or whether one might want to pick a more recent inception such as the tea party movement sawing distrust in public institutions creating some kind of gridlock or profiting from one and already championing some of the religious and neo-conservative themes presentin what the Trumpist crowd is built upon.
Though flirting with fascist ideas and exploring them publicly and complaining about democracy and democratic institutions, trying to game the system and complaining about a lack of national vigor ... hatred of millennials... has been a staple of U.S. conservative politics. So even before Trump the U.S. might have already jumped that stage.

2.Rooting, where a fascist movement, aided by political deadlock and polarization, becomes a player on the national stage

Now Paxton is right, the U.S. is not nearly as deadlocked as Germany or Italy were in the 1920s, where the parliament literally had double digit numbers of fascists AND communists, monarchists, liberals, republicans and democrats (it's always a bad sign if that is a noteworthy quality of a party) and so on and where these groups couldn't even agree on a system of government let alone any concrete political proposals. Nonetheless there have been deadlock situations in the U.S. and Trump has already made concerning comments arguing:

“Under no circumstances, you are promising America tonight, you would never abuse power as retribution against anybody?” Hannity asked Trump in the interview taped in Davenport, Iowa.


“Except for day one,” Trump responded. “I want to close the border and I want to drill, drill, drill.” source

The claims are not as strong as Hitler's who has, and given the circumstances also could, advocate for dismantling democracy in favor of an authoritarian leader principle, without losing voters in the conservative, fascist and monarchist block, but it's not that he hasn't made these claims either.


Arrival to power, where conservatives seeking to control rising leftist opposition invite fascists to share power


Well the conservative establishment has shared a lot of power with Trumpism and while he at least verbally faced a lot of backlash, most critics have fallen in line and have turned a blind eye to almost all crimes, scandals and violations of the rule of law and democratic safeguards. Now Mussoline and Hitler were appointed government by a king or the less folkloric version of one (president), while the U.S. still has elections.


Exercise of power, where the movement and its charismatic leader control the state in balance with state institutions such as the police and traditional elites such as the clergy and business magnates.


Now with regards to Italy and Germany, there were extra-democratic institutions able to provide a framework of government outside the law, while the U.S. has a longer democratic history and it's more that such structure evolve outside of the system by "small government", "privatization", giving out democratically regulated government responsibility to private actors, but it's not that they already have taken control as an oligarchy outside of democracy, have they?
Also if that doesn't just include institutions and elites outside the law, you might also argue that having the supreme court struck down his travel ban, having election workers and board members rejecting his fraud claims on the lack of evidence and whatnot are example of ruling in balance with established institutions. Which for the fascist further increases their need to overcome those. As Trump did, changing the composition of federal courts and the supreme courts. And with project 2025 this could become even worse. Though there the line blurs between Trump and Trumpism. In that Trump denies knowledge or connection with it, though his denials are... mixed. Like he definitely knows those people as they are former or current staff...
He acknowledges that the ideas are extremist:

“the other side is going around trying to make me sound extreme, like I’m an extremist. I’m not. I’m a person with great common sense. I’m not an extremist at all.

He acknowledges that the people behind it are "very very conservative":

“It’s a group of very, very conservative people and they wrote a document that many of the points are fine,” Trump said. “Many of the points are absolutely ridiculous. I have nothing to do with the document. I’ve never seen the document. I’ve seen certain things that are said in it. And it’s a group of very conservative people that probably like me, but it doesn’t matter because it doesn’t speak for me.

But effectively makes a non-statement. Like you can read that both as "Yeah he has no clue and doesn't want to comment before reading" yet at the same time he argues he isn't going to read it and isn't disavowing any of the points or the people on the contrary he literally "many of the points are fine". So it's anybody's guess whether that refers to the extremist sections or filler text along the way.
Though if you don't look at that from the perspective of "is that damning for Trump personally" and more from the perspective "is that enabling actual fascists but not drawing red lines" then you can make a case that it is fascist.
And while Trumps staff pretends as if Trumps statement made clear that no one but himself is supposed to speak in his name (probably true and not off brand for a fascist look at night of long knives) and inner party struggles in "revolutionary movements", the statement of the organization behind it reads differently:

Heritage Foundation President Kevin Roberts said the project had “completed exactly what it set out to do: bringing together over 110 leading conservative organizations to create a unified conservative vision, motivated to devolve power from the unelected administrative state, and returning it to the people.” Roberts said the project was always slated “to conclude its policy drafting after the two party conventions this year, and we are sticking to that timeline.” Although the policy writing portion of the project was finished, he said, “Project 2025 will continue our efforts to build a personnel apparatus for policymakers of all levels—federal, state, and local.”

Source for the project 2025 quotes.
Also his famous:

Anything they do, I wish them luck, but I have nothing to do with them.”

Does not sound like disavowal of extremists.
Though to his credit these are legal shenanigans so far so that is not the Mussolini type fascism that marched on Rome and made the king give him the government or fight a civil war where he'd face the fascists and the communists and thus likely lose (not that the two groups liked each other but neither would be fighting FOR the monarchy). That being said Hitler also seized power through shenanigans and violence without or only minor criminal consequences for him.

5.Radicalization or entropy, where the state either becomes increasingly radical, as did Nazi Germany, or slips into traditional authoritarian rule, as did Fascist Italy.

So far the U.S. dodged that bullet and Trump lost his power grab attempt in 2020, though fingers crossed when people find out that Trumps visions don't come to fruition the response is realizing that it's bullshit and not reacting with more vigorous blaming of minorities and supplying him with more power to pursue his goals and purge his enemies even more effectively.
So you might place the U.S. on stage 3-4 of fascism, so far having failed with stage 5. Though unlikely with Germany post WWI, the social cohesion in the U.S. might be a lot lower, so cutthroat economics and an ideology of individualism permeating especially the conservative parties might some sort of collective nationalist project somewhat of an antithesis. At least on the top levels of the party Trump seems to be successful making people give up their individuality and submit to him and his base wearing uniform (red hats) is also a sign of that, but not sure there is a same tendency for collective action especially as individualism and freedom are still highly praised. So there is some contradiction and Trumps making "Barnum statements" ("there's something for everyone", as seen before) can go either way when people find out their interpretation was actually incorrect. After all 2 people already tried to kill him who previously held sympathetic views (voted for Trump and registered as republican espousing anti-immigration views).
Also another maybe more revealing description of Fascism by Paxton might be "the Anatomy of Fascism" (2004):

Fascism may be defined as a form of political behavior marked by obsessive preoccupation with community decline, humiliation, or victim-hood and by compensatory cults of unity, energy, and purity, in which a mass-based party of committed nationalist militants, working in uneasy but effective collaboration with traditional elites, abandons democratic liberties and pursues with redemptive violence and without ethical or legal restraints goals of internal cleansing and external expansion. (Source)

I mean read his inaugural address... Where he talks extensively of decline, unity, being abused and exploited by other nations. Praises the military calls for "A new national pride will stir our souls, lift our sights, and heal our divisions.". Like at times you might think that he read the previous description as a manual. Though to be fair, a lot of those themes are so deeply ingrained in American politics that I wouldn't be surprised to hear it from a Democrat either, which you can read as unfortunately many Americans seeming to like rhetoric that is borderline fascist. On the other hand you might also read it as "Americans like underdog stories" and going from the bottom to the top is a story with some dramatic range, like sugar and cheese it's a cheap method to make any other meal more palatable. Also with regards to calls for national unity, in many countries that's usually employed as an us vs them narrative, but in case of the U.S. where individualist communities can reach a size where they effectively can form bubbles and live in parallel barely connected realities such a claim might be more benign. So you can give that some benefit of the doubt, but in combination with anti-immigration rhetoric and victim narratives that argue to pushback against foreign threats, that still rings different than unity and healing.
Now enough Paxton, let's take it over to Eco:

1."The cult of tradition", characterized by cultural syncretism, even at the risk of internal contradiction. When all truth has already been revealed by tradition, no new learning can occur, only further interpretation and refinement.

Again that kinda rings differently with actual conservatism at the beginning of the 20th century where people still believed in monarchism and strongmen government, but nonetheless there certainly is a strong social conservative undercurrent to Trumpism and for example with making Transidentities a major campaign point kinda cuts in that direction, that there is no necessity for seeking new solutions if there are no problems that haven't been solved already.
Also the merger of evangelicals with Trump, a known adulterer who doesn't even know how to hold a bible and has apparently never read it, kinda also fits with the contradiction despite calling for traditionalism. Also "Make America Great AGAIN" certainly is reactionary and backwards facing.


"The rejection of modernism", which views the rationalistic development of Western culture since the Enlightenment as a descent into depravity. Eco distinguishes this from a rejection of superficial technological advancement, as many fascist regimes cite their industrial potency as proof of the vitality of their system.


I mean his followers more often speak of "post-modern (neo-marxist)"-conspiracies, but given how little any of them are paying attention to what that means, it might still somewhat fit the mold. Though again updated times updated labels for the enemy.
That being said especially with the religious undercurrent of people comparing him to Jesus.
"3. "The cult of action for action's sake", which dictates that action is of value in itself and should be taken without intellectual reflection. This, says Eco, is connected with anti-intellectualism and irrationalism, and often manifests in attacks on modern culture and science."
Given how much he argues for change without having a plan or doing shit, that fits to a t.

4."Disagreement is treason" – fascism devalues intellectual discourse and critical reasoning as barriers to action, as well as out of fear that such analysis will expose the contradictions embodied in a syncretistic faith.

Again look at the people in his team or his former team mates and that's a 100% fit.

5."Fear of difference", which fascism seeks to exploit and exacerbate, often in the form of racism or an appeal against foreigners and immigrants.

Fear of immigrants is certainly stoked and Trump has shown a history of racism. Not yet on the Hitler level where it explains everything... though actually "build the wall" and anti-immigration rhetoric is pretty much all there is to his program, isn't it?

6."Appeal to a frustrated middle class", fearing economic pressure from the demands and aspirations of lower social groups.

Again pretty close fit, just read his inaugural address...


"Obsession with a plot" and the hyping-up of an enemy threat. This often combines an appeal to xenophobia with a fear of disloyalty and sabotage from marginalized groups living within the society. Eco also cites Pat Robertson's book The New World Order as a prominent example of a plot obsession.


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Election_denial_movement_in_the_United_States#/media/File:20240524_Trump_groundwork_for_election_denial.svg  Picture of when starts to question election results before the respective election...

8.Fascist societies rhetorically cast their enemies as "at the same time too strong and too weak". On the one hand, fascists play up the power of certain disfavored elites to encourage in their followers a sense of grievance and humiliation. On the other hand, fascist leaders point to the decadence of those elites as proof of their ultimate feebleness in the face of an overwhelming popular will.

I'm running out of time, but I'm certain you can find those plentiful.

9."Pacifism is trafficking with the enemy" because "life is permanent warfare" – there must always be an enemy to fight. Both fascist Germany under Hitler and Italy under Mussolini worked first to organize and clean up their respective countries and then build the war machines that they later intended to and did use, despite Germany being under restrictions of the Versailles treaty to not build a military force. This principle leads to a fundamental contradiction within fascism: the incompatibility of ultimate triumph with perpetual war.

Now that is somewhat of an outlier in that while he has endorsed violence, torture and police brutality and argued for more not less and wants military parades for himself, apart from figurative scolding of his team mates for not fighting hard enough he has not yet made it officially his platform to go to open war and combativeness, though he hasn't effectively distanced himselves from those who do/did either...

10."Contempt for the weak", which is uncomfortably married to a chauvinistic popular elitism, in which every member of society is superior to outsiders by virtue of belonging to the in-group. Eco sees in these attitudes the root of a deep tension in the fundamentally hierarchical structure of fascist polities, as they encourage leaders to despise their underlings, up to the ultimate leader, who holds the whole country in contempt for having allowed him to overtake it by force.

A sense of nationalism is often common but given how he uses the ingroup outgroup discrepancy in his inaugural address that's probably also close enough.

11."Everybody is educated to become a hero", which leads to the embrace of a cult of death. As Eco observes, "[t]he Ur-Fascist hero is impatient to die. In his impatience, he more frequently sends other people to death."

American dream?

12."Machismo", which sublimates the difficult work of permanent war and heroism into the sexual sphere. Fascists thus hold "both disdain for women and intolerance and condemnation of nonstandard sexual habits, from chastity to homosexuality".

... yeah.

13."Selective populism" – the people, conceived monolithically, have a common will, distinct from and superior to the viewpoint of any individual. As no mass of people can ever be truly unanimous, the leader holds himself out as the interpreter of the popular will (though truly he alone dictates it). Fascists use this concept to delegitimize democratic institutions they accuse of "no longer represent[ing] the voice of the people".

Also pretty close to what he's doing.


"Newspeak" – fascism employs and promotes an impoverished vocabulary in order to limit critical reasoning.


Well his crowd of "words have lost their meaning if they apply to us" certainly do that constantly.
Now this was a bit rushed so I might take a look at it again later, but yeah a shocking amount of points fit shockingly well while all fit at least in some regard.

Today I learned 30,000 characters is the upper limit for how long an answer can possibly be on stack exchange :)

It probably should be lower, it takes ages to read that many characters and we don't want people to write monographs, rather to cite and link to work of others (like you do) and summaries so people can if they want follow them.
